# Delphi7 TImageList visual form inheritance

Tags: forms, delphi, inheritance, delphi-7

What is the correct usage of TImageList when it comes to visual form inheritance? I have this standard toolbar in the base form that uses them.

(1) Do they get replicated in descendant forms, hence multiplying memory usage?

(2) Is it advisable to place the TImagesList in a separate unit/datamodule and reference them from base or descendant forms?

(3) Is there an overall benefit of assigning images/glyphs at runtime over designtime?

TIA

Comment: Massive benefit to assigning at runtime. Doing so allows you to load images that match prevailing dpi setting.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, David. I take that as an affirmation.